# How to have Pivot.Background appear like Panorama Background

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing a custom UI witch i need it to be a Pivot but i would like to have the stretched through items background just like in the Panorama

Has anyone found a way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance